# How to change opacity when the form is on desktop level

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm writing a tool for my own, that replaces the windows desktop.
The code, that puts my program to desktop level is the following (C#):

```
        IntPtr hwndf = this.Handle;
        IntPtr hwndParent = FindWindow("ProgMan", null);
        SetParent(hwndf, hwndParent);
```

Cause of this I can't set the opacity of the form to anything else than 100% (otherwise the program won't start).

Since I didn't find a good way to make single controls semi transparent I want to ask if somebody has an idea either how to make the whole form or the controls (eg. `GridView`s and `TextBox`es) opaque or make the background of all controls transparent.

Comment: Why do you want to make the form or particular controls transparent if you replace the desktop, i.e. what would you like to show underneath?

Comment: what exactly you mean with wont start?the child window you set its parent?and...is that child window you are trying to set opacity?

Comment: Since there is no reply on what exactly is going on in your app i will go with Hit & Miss. try SetLayeredWindowAttributes function,since you're making an unmanaged API call....

Comment: looks like you may be stuck forever if still keeping on using that approach. In Winforms, we can't make the child control transparent using some win32 function or provided property. I suggest you should try hooking up **when the desktop is shown**, then show your form on top of it, of course we don't use `SetParent` so that your form's opacity can be changed easily.

Comment: Changing the Opacity property changes the Handle property.  A side-effect of Winforms having to destroy and re-create the window so it can change the the WS_EX_LAYERED style flag.  You must therefore put this code in an override for the OnHandleCreated method.

Comment: @Gorgsenegger: i want to show a wallpaper behind the controls, they dont look that ugly, eg. a big textbox. So if they aure transparent in front of the form the background image shines though

Comment: @terrybozzio: my proramm seems to hang up. if I pause the debugging im at the line: Application.Run(new Form1());
I tried with SetLayeredWindowAttributes, but it does only work if I uncomment the parent code i posted above

Comment: @Hans Passant: when i put the code in the onCreated overide like this. protected override void OnHandleCreated(){} it is executed but seems to have no effect anymore.

Comment: @King King: seems like I need to do it like your suggestion